# Error in creating index on a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have created the following function in my database

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[CountUseer](@couponid INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN
(
  SELECT Count(cu.id) NofUses  --- this can only return one column
  FROM   Coupon as  c
  JOIN CouponUse as cu
    ON c.id = cu.couponid
  WHERE cu.couponid = @couponid
 )
 END
```

Then I run this query

```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.Coupon
   ADD NofUses AS dbo.CountUseer(Id)
```

Now when I try to create an index on the column `NofUses` :

```
CREATE INDEX Noofusesindex ON Coupon (NofUses)
```

I get this error:

> *Column 'NofUses' in table 'Coupon' cannot be used in an index or
>   statistics or as a partition key because it is non-deterministic.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the error message really says it all: since this function is **non-deterministic** (e.g. when you call it with the same input parameters, there's no guarantee you'll get the same results every time), it **cannot be indexed**.

The only way around this would be to make it a regular column (not based on a function), and just update the value stored in that column on a regular basis (by a SQL Agent job, for instance, or by a trigger on the `CouponUse` table, or some other mechanism)